# Chef recipe - not_if with SQL query result

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have in my recipe this block:

```
bash "Create admin database tables" do
    code "mysql -u root -D admindb < /vagrant/files/admin.sql"
    not_if shell_out("mysql -u root -s --skip-column-names -e 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_name)>0 FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = \"admindb\";'").stdout().chomp()
end
```

Result of select query is `0` or `1` written to stdout (nothing more). I would like to run shell command only, if result of query will be `0`. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a Ruby equality operator inside the block. Since you said "only if" the output is 0, it would be simpler to do this with `only_if` rather than `not_if`:

```
only_if { shell_out("mysql -u root -s --skip-column-names -e 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_name)>0 FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = \"admindb\";'").stdout.chomp == '0' }
```